# SQL Queries as a Transaction in Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I am looking to execute a few SQL queries as a transaction in PowerShell. However, I am getting errors and could not find a suitable answer.
Besides the error, is BeginTransaction() and CommitTransaction() the way to perform transaction in Powershell? Intellisense doesn't seem to show CommitTransaction() method.

Error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been 
initialized
```

Code:

```
try {
    #SQL Connection
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server,1433;Initial Catalog=$Database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=$UserID;Password=$Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;;"

    $Connection.Open()

    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection

    #Begin Transaction
    $Connection.BeginTransaction()

    #INSERT into PROJECT table 
    $input_2 = $projectName
    $input_3 = $blobUri + $configFileName
    $input_4 = $key
    $input_5 = $projectType
    $input_6 = $projectIsActive

    $sql =
    "
    begin 
        INSERT INTO PROJECT 
        ([PROJECT_NAME],[CONFIGURATION_LOCATION],[ENCRYPTION_KEY],[PROJECT_TYPE],[IS_ACTIVE],[CREATED_DATETIME])
        select '$input_2', '$input_3', '$input_4', '$input_5', '$input_6', cast(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GETDATE()) AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' as datetime)
    end
    " 
    $Command.CommandText = $sql
    $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    #Get Project ID from PROJECT table
    $sql =
    "
    begin 
        SELECT TOP 1 PROJECT_ID FROM PROJECT WHERE PROJECT_NAME='$projectName'
    end
    " 
    $Command.CommandText = $sql
    $projectID = $Command.ExecuteScalar() 


    #Commit Transaction
    $Connection.CommitTrasaction()

    #Close Connection
    $Connection.Close()
}
Catch {
    throw   

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the `Transaction` property of the `SqlCommand` to the  transaction object that is returned by `BeginTransaction`:

```
$command.Transaction = $connection.BeginTransaction()
try {
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $command.Transaction.Commit()
}
catch {
   try {
       $command.Transaction.Rollback()
    }
    catch {
       # Microsoft recommends to catch and log and/or ignore rollback exceptions
    }
    throw
}
```

Note: The rollback itself could also throw. You might want to put another try-catch around it. Rollback-errors are usually safe to ignore (or just log), the transaction might have already been rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

There's a type in $Connection.CommitTrasaction()